# Should I flag questions that may attract low quality answers?

Tags: discussion, flags

I'm surprised the following question has 24 answers currently:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018772/core-java-code-error

However, many of them looks horrible in terms of quality,eg: code only:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505392/5263291

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37273613/5263291

Suspicious NAA:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37538598/5263291

Can I flag such type of questions so that anybody else would scan and check the answers?

Comment: wish I could _unsee_ that question and its "answers". I am generally not fond of bringing low views questions to Meta (this one had <700) but this seems to be rare case when this looks justified. Awful, really awful stuff

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160901005852/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018772/core-java-code-error in case you are wondering [trigger warning]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is a bit of a tire fire.  Let's start analyzing this one.

First of all, the question states that they're not getting the expected output.  However, it's not immediately clear what *their* output is, or how it relates to their expected output - for example, their expected output goes up to 30, but the loop contains values up to 100.  This makes it an ideal candidate to be flagged for closure as "why isn't this code working", since they're still missing a few key details.

Second, the answers on this are ***abysmal.***  Not a **single one** goes into any detail to explain ***what*** the actual problem is, which makes the quality of these answers just...terrible.  There's no flag to deal with terrible answers; chiefly, the only reason you'd flag an answer is to declare it as spam, not an answer, or something that you think a moderator should genuinely look into - and poor quality ain't one of those things.

The only real recourse you have for a question/answer set like this:

- Downvote liberally.
- Flag the question for closure as, "Why doesn't this code work?"
- Downvote the really terrible code-only answers.
- Then, move on with your life.

After you've done your due diligence, the system will take care of the rest.

Comment: This would have been a reasonable use-case for protection, since quite a few of the answers *were* posted by people with <10 reputation. Not all, mind you, and this isn't something that Gstestso could have done himself, but it is one of the rare cases where manual protection is useful. (The solution that has now been implemented is, of course, even better.)